# Как распарсить raw post запрос в NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

Добрый вечер.

Нужно получить содержимое post запроса. 
Сам post запрос я получаю chunk-ами, и в raw виде.

(Как получаю и что с ним делаю далее)

```
app.post('/', function(req,res,next){ 

  var data = [];

  req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
    data.push(chunk);
  });

  req.on('end', function() { 
    var buffer = ...; // Как получить содержимое?
    var file = Buffer.concat(buffer);
    res.end('try');
  });
});
```

Из html-а отправляется такой вот запрос:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="image_upload" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send File">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Нужно получить бинарные данные и название файла. Как это сделать? Через что парсить?

Comment: в момент 'end' в переменной data будет содержимое запроса в виде массива объектов Buffer, разве нет?

Answer (score -3):

Воспользуйтесь соответствующим модулем - [Busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy).

```
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

// default options, no immediate parsing
app.use(busboy());
// ...
app.use(function(req, res) {
  if (req.busboy) {
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      // ...
    });
    req.busboy.on('field', function(key, value, keyTruncated, valueTruncated) {
      // ...
    });
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
  }
  // etc ...
});

// default options, immediately start reading from the request stream and
// parsing
app.use(busboy({ immediate: true }));
// ...
app.use(function(req, res) {
  if (req.busboy) {
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      // ...
    });
    req.busboy.on('field', function(key, value, keyTruncated, valueTruncated) {
      // ...
    });
  }
  // etc ...
});

// any valid Busboy options can be passed in also
app.use(busboy({
  highWaterMark: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
  }
}));
```

Comment: Хорошая библиотека, но мне больше подошел сам busboy, он действительно реализует мою задумку и работает так как нужно.